# transform scale css 3 SVG

Tags: css, svg, transform, scale

I have the next code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGRzVq

```
<style>
   #pulse {animation : pulse 1s infinite 1s, hideme 15s;}
   @keyframes pulse {0%{transform: scale(0,0);opacity: 0.5} 100%{transform: scale(1,1);opacity: 1.5}
   @keyframes hideme {100%{display: none}}
</style>
```

But looks like `"transform: scale(0,0)"` is not working in `IE 11`, can I use another transformation for to change the size of the circle ?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support CSS transforms on SVG elements.  You might want to use one of the SVG libraries such as Snap etc.  Or you can do it manually by manipulating the transform attribute with JS.

Comment: whenever it works with opacity. looks like it's enought